# OWIN Cookie Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I can't seem to get OWIN to work with Cookie based authentication. I have configured my OWIN token endpoint in Startup as:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
   TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
   Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
   AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
   AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

I have also configured Cookie Authentication:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

Now when I hit the `/token` endpoint I get the bearer token in response and a cookie is also set on client side with the token.

Next up I have a controller that is decorated with the `Authorize` Attribute. When I try to access any method I get a 401 Unauthorized response, even though the cookie is sent with the request. It seems OWIN is not honoring the cookie for authentication.

Am I missing some thing here, probably some type of configuration? All of this works great if I set the Authorization header with bearer token but why does it not work with cookie only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, in the WebApi Config the following line was ignoring the cookie and looked at the Bearer Token.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Commenting it out made the cookie based Authentication work.