# Keep using cookies for authentication in Web API with OWIN and app.UseWebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'd like to keep using same cookies in MVC and API parts of my app. I know this isn't very secure but still.
Everything works if I create a new MVC project in VS, Web API is set up from Global.asax using `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)`.
But as soon as I'm trying to use OWIN to configure Web API I run into a problem where User is always null in my API controllers.

Here's my code from `Startup.cs`:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Controllers work, routes too, same WebApiConfig.cs file is used. However the User is null in my API controllers now. What's missing from my instance of `HttpConfiguration` that is present in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`?

I need to use my own instance of `HttpConfiguration` instead of using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` because I'm planning to use Autofac and it doesn't work with `GlobalConfiguration` as mentioned [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration)

**EDIT:**

My `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
// and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
// Configure the sign in cookie
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your Startup.Auth or wherever the authentication and authorisation is configured for MVC

Comment: I've edited the question. It's the same file generated by the project template, I've only commented out stuff used in two-factor and external auth, since I'm not going to use it.

Comment: I should also mention that I've tried using HostAuthenticationFilter(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie) which was supposed to process the cookie, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use Bearer token authentication? You can start using it with just a few lines of configuration, and it means that consumers of your API do not need to run in a browser like they would using Cookie authentication

Comment: how are you getting user? are you using `HttpContext.User.Identity`?

Comment: I'm using `Request.User`

Answer (score 4):

> What's missing from my instance of HttpConfiguration that is present
>   in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration?

[GlobalConfiguration.cs Source code from Codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/GlobalConfiguration.cs)

The main difference between when you create a new `HttpConfiguration` and the one In `GlobalConfiguration`...

```
public static class GlobalConfiguration
{
    private static Lazy<HttpConfiguration> _configuration = CreateConfiguration();

    //...other code removed for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the global <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static HttpConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get { return _configuration.Value; }
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity

    private static Lazy<HttpConfiguration> CreateConfiguration()
    {
        return new Lazy<HttpConfiguration>(() =>
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(new HostedHttpRouteCollection(RouteTable.Routes));
            ServicesContainer services = config.Services;
            Contract.Assert(services != null);
            services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new WebHostAssembliesResolver());
            services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver());
            services.Replace(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new WebHostBufferPolicySelector());
            services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
                new WebHostExceptionHandler(services.GetExceptionHandler()));
            return config;
        });
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Also when looking at how the `UseWebAPi` extension in 
[WebApiAppBuilderExtensions.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/WebApiAppBuilderExtensions.cs)

```
public static IAppBuilder UseWebApi(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    if (builder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("builder");
    }

    if (configuration == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");
    }

    HttpServer server = new HttpServer(configuration);

    try
    {
        HttpMessageHandlerOptions options = CreateOptions(builder, server, configuration);
        return UseMessageHandler(builder, options);
    }
    catch
    {
        server.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

...the configuration is wrapped in its own `HttpServer` which overrides the default one used by `GlobalConfiguration`.

Looking through the documentation you included, I eventually came across [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/owin.html#owin)

> For **standard IIS hosting**, the `HttpConfiguration` is
>   `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`.
>
> For self hosting, the `HttpConfiguration` is your
>   `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` instance.
>
> For **OWIN integration**, the `HttpConfiguration` is the one you create in
>   your app startup class and pass to the Web API middleware.

With standard IIS hosting, IIS handles user Authentication and Identification which it plugs into the `HttpConfiguration` and pipeline under the hood for you. When you `new` up `HttpConfiguration` your self you don't have the benefits of IIS to manage Authentication for you so your `User` remains `null`.

From your post you indicate that you are using more than one instance of `HttpConfiguration` which looks like you are trying to mix IIS and OWIN.

Looking at this question : [OWIN Cookie Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333018/5233410)

The answer shows that in the WebApi Config the following line was ignoring the cookie.

```
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
// If you don't want the OWIN authentication to flow to your Web API then call 
// SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication on your HttpConfiguration. 
// This blocks all host level authentication at that point in the pipeline.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Commenting it out made the cookie based Authentication work.

UPDATE:

You indicated...

> Controllers work, routes too, same `WebApiConfig.cs` file is used.
>   However the `User` is `null` in my API controllers now

Take a look at...

**[Combining Authentication Filters with Host-Level Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)**

> “Host-level authentication” is authentication performed by the host
>   (such as IIS), before the request reaches the Web API framework.
>
> Often, you may want to to enable host-level authentication for the
>   rest of your application, but disable it for your Web API controllers.
>   For example, a typical scenario is to enable Forms Authentication at
>   the host level, but use token-based authentication for Web API.
>
> To disable host-level authentication inside the Web API pipeline, call
>   `config.SuppressHostPrincipal()` in your configuration. **This causes
>   Web API to remove the `IPrincipal` from any request that enters the
>   Web API pipeline**. Effectively, it "un-authenticates" the request.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SuppressHostPrincipal();

        // Other configuration code not shown...
    }
}
```

If in your scenario you have the following in your web api configuration, it would explain why your `User` is always `null`. I suggest you comment it out or remove it all together.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been clear enough. I need to use my own constructed HttpConfiguration because I'm planning to use Autofac. Autofac documentation explicitly mentions that:

// Get your `HttpConfiguration`. In OWIN, you'll create one
// rather than using `GlobalConfiguration`.
`var config = new HttpConfiguration();`

Comment: The difference between `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` and my own configuration is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @devmiles.com where will you be hosting the api? IIS?

Comment: So far I've only ran it from VS in IISExpress

Comment: @devmiles.com I found the source code for `GlobalConfiguration` take a look to see what it does when creating `HttpConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem when I transferred to OWIN from a WebApi only service. My user was also null even though it was correctly authenticated. In my case I had missed adding the HostAuthenticationFilter in after suppressing the Default Host Authentication.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(YourAuthenticationType));
```

Check that you have not forgotten your authentication filter here. I've done this successfully using Unity (rather than Autofac) but the principal is exactly the same. In my OWIN startup this order:

```
ConfigureAuth(app);
WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
```

Comment: Just noticed your comment about using the host authentication filter. What order have you set up security in? That was another problem I noticed. I had to do the suppression and filter add right at the top of my webapiconfig.

Comment: ok, i'm going to try it in a couple of hours. Interesting, I was quite sure that `SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()` is something I don't need for sure.

Comment: heh... after adding these two lines my API controller got the principal, but my mvc controllers lost it...

Comment: Hahaha, what do you mean lost it? Perhaps I can help?

Comment: `Request.IsAuthenticated == false`

Comment: Not sure if you've read this, but looks like you need to move from MVC when using Owin and just use WebApi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238424/run-asp-net-mvc-as-owin-middleware